# How to make list of combinations of elements from particular collections

Tags: java, recursion

I need to make lists of combinations of elements from particular collections in specified order.

E.g. list

> [[a, b], [X, Y, Z], [1, 2]]

should return:

> [[a, X, 1], [b, X, 1], [a, Y, 1], [b, Y, 1], [a, Z, 1], [b, Z, 1], [a,
>   X, 2], [b, X, 2], [a, Y, 2], [b, Y, 2], [a, Z, 2], [b, Z, 2]]

I tried to solve it using iteration but it works only for list for 3 sublists in this case (if I'd like to use the function for 6 subelements it won't work properply). Could anyone suggest more flexible recursive solution?

```
    List<List<String>> result;
    List<List<String>> x;
    //filling the x list of lists
    List<String> tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.get(2).size(); i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < x.get(1).size(); j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < x.get(0).size(); k++)
            {
                tmp = new List<>();
                tmp.add(x.get(0).get(k));
                tmp.add(x.get(1).get(j));
                tmp.add(x.get(2).get(i));

                result.add(tmp);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes it is. 3 loops can easily do that

Comment: @jhamon, But the function should work for collections of any size, so basically it should work for lists e.g. 6 sublists too.

Comment: I'm not sure my current solution change anything, but if it cause not response and minuses - I updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
private static void solve(List<List<String>> x, int item, List<String> combination) {
    if (item == x.size()) { // We have reached the end of the list i.e, traversed all rows 
        result.add(combination);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x.get(item).size(); i++) {
        List<String> current = new ArrayList<>(combination);
        current.add(x.get(item).get(i));
        solve(x, item + 1, current);
    }
}
```

---

```
solve(x, 0, new ArrayList<>());
```

The core of the logic is to make a recursive call passing a list obtained by copying the `combination` list and adding each element of the current list (`item`) to it.

Comment: You can spare a lot of calls if you check whether we've reached the end of `x`  inside the loop instead of the beginning of the function.

Comment: This function gives the combinations but in slightly different order. Nevertheless, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via resursion.

All you need is a function which accepts `List<List<String>>` as input, `List<String>` as the common prefixes of all the combinations, and `List<List<String>>` target where you store the result.

Inside the function you should take the first entry from input, for each string in this entry add it to a copy of prefix, and call recursively itself with the new prefix and with input without the first entry.

```
[[a, b], [c, d]] - input
[] - common prefix
[] - result
```

iterate `[a, b]`, call recursively itself on each iteration. On the first iteration your function will be called with `[c, d]` as input and `[a]` as common prefix, on the second - with `[c, d]` as input and `[b]` as common prefix etc. When input has only one element, don't iterate, just put all the combinations of common prefix and entry from input into result